# Kotlin codelab: no return value, so why is generic type returned?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was recently going through a [lesson](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-bootcamp-generics/#2) in Google codelabs for Kotlin, and I could not understand this part:

This is the definition for Aquarium:

```kotlin
class Aquarium<T: WaterSupply>(val waterSupply: T) {
    fun addWater() {
        check(!waterSupply.needsProcessing) { "water supply needs processing first" }
        println("adding water from $waterSupply")
    }    
}
```

> Look at the Aquarium class and you'll see that the generic type is only ever returned when getting the property waterSupply. There aren't any methods that take a value of type T as a parameter (except for defining it in the constructor). Kotlin lets you define out types for exactly this case, and it can infer extra information about where the types are safe to use. Similarly, you can define in types for generic types that are only ever passed into methods, not returned. This allows Kotlin to do extra checks for code safety.

There is only one function in the Aquarium class, which returns nothing (Unit), not WaterSupply (This example probably means WaterSupply by the "generic type"). I'm confused as to why the codelab is saying that the generic type (WaterSupply) is returned, when nothing is supposed to be returned?

Comment: 'val waterSupply' is a property so it can be accessed (returned) by calling 'aquarium.waterSupply'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is this part:

> the generic type is only ever returned when getting the property waterSupply

The `Aquarium` class' constructor takes a `val waterSupply: T`. Note the `val` part; that causes the Kotlin compiler to expose `waterSupply` as a property of any Aquarium instance. Hence, you can call `someAquariumInstance.waterSupply` and something of type `T` will be returned.